# Create new sheet in Excel using template

Tags: vba, excel, templates

I use two workbooks for my business. I have saved both as templates, with one named **sales invoices** and the other named **monies collected**.

What I would like to do is when I click the new sheet button, a new sheet will be created within the workbook and the data and formulas from the required template are imported to the new sheet.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Worksheets("Template").Cells.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds great! Show us what you've tried and tell us how it's failing, and you'll have an answerable question =)

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
Worksheets("Template").Cells.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
End Sub

Comment: You need to [edit] your question with all the relevant information...

Comment: Thanks Mat I have pasted the current code to the original question.

Comment: how are you calling this sub and also where are your references to the source and destination workbooks as well as any possibly required opening of source workbook so you can copy data across?